# Password protected multi-user blog?

Tags: webapp-rec, blog

I'm looking for a freely available blog that has the following features:

- password-protected: only user which are registered can view blog and add comments
- multi-user: it has to be possible that more than one user posts a new blog entry

I'm hosting this by myself.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are hosting yourself, your best bet is to install Wordpress and enable the multi-blog option.

You can check the wordpress codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page for more information. It explains everything. If you still have questions, you can find a whole host of WP gurus at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would recommend [BlogEngine.NET](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/)

This has recently been upgraded to version 2.0 with a whole host of improvements.

By default it doesn't provide the ability to allow only registered users to comment. However, as it is completely open source you can modify the files yourself.

It would be as easy as adding a simple check in the CommentView.ascx .cs file to enable comments if the user is authenticated.  There is [a post on the codeplex site](http://blogengine.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=92721) with some information on this.

This naturally all depends on whether you are a developer or not.

**EDIT:**

Ah, I've just noticed you have tagged your question with the `php` tag - blogengine.net is a .NET product.  I'll leave this answer here for other users that may find your post.

Answer (score 0):

Google's Blogger meets those criteria, provided you never want to invite more than 100 people to either read or post to the blog.   (That's 100 in total, not 100 for each option).

Comment: Thanks, this would be great if it wouldn't be require to register a google account.

Answer (score 0):

Google's blogging service allows your criteria. Just check it out. Allows multi user, restrict access to registered users etc.